# css issue why isn't my pictures being displayed?

Tags: css

this is my first time using stack overflow so i would be grateful if you could answer this for me. I have an issue with my css because it is not displaying the three images that i want to be displayed in my website. Two of the images are for the top border and bottom border of the website and the header image is the main image that will be displayed in the website.
Down below is a copy of my css, so if you could get back to me i will be more than grateful thank-you.

```
   body, h1, p, nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: "#B0E0E6";
}
table{id:"Table_01" width="1500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"




}
img {
    id:top ;
    src:"205&#x20;images/top.jpg";
    width:1750px;
    height:154px;

   margin-top: 5px;
}

nav ul li {
    display:inline;

}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid black;
    border-top: 0px solid black;
    padding-left: 300px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
}
h1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 90px;

    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:150px;
    position: relative;
}
h2 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: black;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: opx;

}

h3 {  
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    color: white;
    margin-right:155px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    text-align: top;
 }




  }
 header { 
    background-image: url('banner.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:400px;
    width:1750px;

    margin-top:250px;
    position:relative;
    float: left;


}





 }


footer ul {
    list-style: none;
}
footer ul li {
    display:inline;
}
footer ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    height: 50px;
    border-bottom: 0px solid black;

    padding-left: 300px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
footer ul li a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: black;
}
footer {
    background-color: white;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 1750px;
    color: white;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}
img {

    src:"205&#x20;images/bottom.jpg";
    width:1750px;
    height:132px;
    alt:"";
    position: relative;
    bottom: 600px;
}

nav {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 1750px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 130px;
}
article {
    background-color:#ADD8E6 ;
    color: black;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    }
forms{

 margin-left:300px;
 width: 10em;
 margin-bottom: 300px


}

#page {
    background-color: #ADD8E6;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: You have many syntax errors in your css file. Especially in your rules for tables.

Comment: @rekire: "syntax errors" is putting it lightly. :)

Comment: Your table rule seems to imply that you're assuming you can put HTML attributes in your CSS, which is not the case. There is some overlap in what they do, but HTML and CSS are completely different languages. You also seem to be assuming that putting id:top; will select the image with the id of "top". But the way to do that is to replace the selector (img) with #top.

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about the CSS basics. A good point to start is the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS). You have several syntax errors in your css file. Try this here:

```
.YourImageClass {
    background:url("images/top.jpg");
    width: 1750px;
    height: 154px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

But note that this only works for elements with the *YourImageClass* class. E.g.:

```
<div class="YourImageClass">...</div>
```